# Why is class extension calling private method of original class?

Tags: java

In this code:

```
public abstract class Bird {
    private void fly() {
        System.out.println("Bird is flying");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bird bird = new Pelican();
        bird.fly();
    }
}

class Pelican extends Bird {
    protected void fly() {
        System.out.println("Pelican is flying");
    }
}
```

Please explain why the output of this is "Bird is flying", since private members are not inherited and I have a Pelican instance in Bird?

Comment: You can't override a `private` method. For some reason I'm surprised this compiles at all.

Comment: You are not overriding fly method from inherited class.

Comment: it's not about i'm overriding something or not, it's about how Pelican instance gets private code of his parent...

Comment: summarize all comments i assume  - Bird reference do not let Pelican instance to reach his own method fly(), and only because main() method placed in Bird-class private  Bird-class method fly() is invoked. Also if access modifier in parent class would be protected then parent method would be overriden and child version would be invoked. Am i correct?

Answer (score -1):

When the reference type is Bird, the object can only access the methods within the class Bird, despite being of type Pelican. The reference type always means a constraint and cannot access fields of e.g. subclasses.

Comment: the reference is assigned of Pelican

Comment: Bird bird = new Pelican(): bird is the reference to the object and it's of type Bird. Pelican is the type of the object that is stored in memory. There's a difference between reference and object.

Comment: Yes `bird` is defined as a `Bird`, but that's not how polymorphism usually works. In this case it does because the method of the base class is defined as `private`, but that's not the norm. If that method was `public` or `protected` it would have printed `Pelican is flying` even if `bird` is defined as a `Bird`

Comment: I see what you're saying. Sorry about that, I'll delete to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Concept 1 :- 
when you make the private methods it is access only within the class.
it can not inherited. 

Concept 2:- 
here the code 

       private void fly() {
            System.out.println("Bird is flying");
        }
can not inherited.

so the code in the `Pelican` class is not inherited and it is treated as `Pelican` class own method.

    protected void fly() {
        System.out.println("Pelican is flying");
    }

Comment: Thanks alot for clarifying!